# my native android app does not run in Lenovo (6.0 or lower)

Tags: android, java-native-interface

my android app contain some native code(.c files) and I have use JNI to implement
native code with in android app, after that I have generated signed apk but that apk does not support in Lenovo mobiles (marshmallow and lower )versions

Comment: Did you get any exceptions while debugging on lenovo mobile in IDE

Comment: no, there is no exception it is a signed apk